# Pascal Variable is not stacking

Tags: pascal

so i need to create a food ordering system in pascal , i have done the program but the program only give me one line of food when i ordered 2 or more types of food

```
    program orderfood;
var
choice,ramen,sashimi,nigi,tei:integer;
nramen,nsashimi,nnigi,ntei:integer;
Money:Text;
count:integer;
NigiMoney,RamenMoney,TeiMoney,SashimiMoney,FinalMoney:integer;
TeiName,RamenName,SashimiName,NigiName,i:string;
a:array [1..4] of string;
b:integer;
procedure Menu;
begin
   writeln('/===============\');
   writeln('|Welcome to the |');
   writeln('|  Japan House! |');
   writeln('| 1. Ramen      |');
   writeln('| 2. Sashimi    |');
   writeln('| 3. Nigirizushi|');
   writeln('| 4. Teishoku   |');
   writeln('| 5. Receipt    |');
   writeln('| 9. Leave      |');
   writeln('\===============/');
   writeln('Please Enter your choice!');
   readln(choice);
end;

procedure OrderRamen;
 begin
   writeln('Choice For Ramen:');
   writeln('1.Shoyu Ramen $38');
   writeln('2.Tonkotsu Ramen $37');
   writeln('3.Shio Ramen $35');
   writeln('4.Miso Ramen $39');
   writeln('5.Tsukemen $45');
   writeln('6.Instant Ramen Noddles $30');
   writeln('Previous =0');
   writeln('Enter your choice: ');
   readln(ramen);
   case ramen of
   1:RamenName:='Shoyu Ramen';
   2:RamenName:='Tonkotsu Ramen';
   3:RamenName:='Shio Ramen';
   4:RamenName:='Miso Ramen';
   5:RamenName:='Tsukemen';
   6:RamenName:='Instant Ramen Noddles';
   end;
   if ramen=0
   then Menu
   else write('How many ramen do you want ? ');
   readln(nramen);
   if nramen>1 then
   case ramen of
      1:RamenMoney:=nramen*13;
      2:RamenMoney:=nramen*20;
      3:RamenMoney:=nramen*18;
      4:RamenMoney:=nramen*15;
      5:RamenMoney:=nramen*22;
      6:RamenMoney:=nramen*22;
   end;
   if nramen=1 then
   case ramen of
      1:RamenMoney:=13;
      2:RamenMoney:=20;
      3:RamenMoney:=18;
      4:RamenMoney:=15;
      5:RamenMoney:=22;
      6:RamenMoney:=22;
   end;
end;

procedure OrderSashimi;
   begin
   writeln('Choice For Sashimi:');
   writeln('1.Sake $41');
   writeln('2.Akami $40');
   writeln('3.Chutoro $50');
   writeln('4.Otoro $70');
   writeln('5.Hotate $45');
   writeln('6.Ikura $40');
   writeln('Previous =0');
   writeln('Enter your choice: ');
   readln(sashimi);
   case sashimi of
   1:SashimiName:='Sake';
   2:SashimiName:='Akami';
   3:SashimiName:='Chutoro';
   4:SashimiName:='Otoro';
   5:SashimiName:='Hotate';
   6:SashimiName:='Ikura';
   end;
   if sashimi=0
   then Menu
   else write('How many sashimi do you want ? ');
   readln(nsashimi);
   if nsashimi>1 then
   case sashimi of
      1:SashimiMoney:=nsashimi*13;
      2:SashimiMoney:=nsashimi*20;
      3:SashimiMoney:=nsashimi*18;
      4:SashimiMoney:=nsashimi*15;
      5:SashimiMoney:=nsashimi*22;
      6:SashimiMoney:=nsashimi*22;
   end;
   if nsashimi=1 then
   case sashimi of
      1:SashimiMoney:=13;
      2:SashimiMoney:=20;
      3:SashimiMoney:=18;
      4:SashimiMoney:=15;
      5:SashimiMoney:=22;
      6:SashimiMoney:=22;
   end;
end;

procedure OrderNigirizushi;
   begin
   nigi:=0;
   writeln('Choice For Nigirizushi:');
   writeln('1.Tamago $13');
   writeln('2.Sake $20');
   writeln('3.Maguro $18');
   writeln('4.Ebi $15');
   writeln('5.Ikuro $22');
   writeln('6.Kani $20');
   writeln('Previous =0');
   writeln('Enter your choice: ');
   readln(nigi);
   case nigi of
   1:NigiName:='Tamago';
   2:NigiName:='Sake';
   3:NigiName:='Maguro';
   4:NigiName:='Ebi';
   5:NigiName:='Ikuro';
   6:NigiName:='Kani';
   end;
   if nigi=0
   then Menu
   else write('How many nigirizushi do you want ? ');
   readln(nnigi);
   if nnigi>1 then
   case nigi of
      1:NigiMoney:=nnigi*13;
      2:NigiMoney:=nnigi*20;
      3:NigiMoney:=nnigi*18;
      4:NigiMoney:=nnigi*15;
      5:NigiMoney:=nnigi*22;
      6:NigiMoney:=nnigi*22;
   end;
   if nnigi=1 then
   case nigi of
      1:NigiMoney:=13;
      2:NigiMoney:=20;
      3:NigiMoney:=18;
      4:NigiMoney:=15;
      5:NigiMoney:=22;
      6:NigiMoney:=22;
   end;

   end;
procedure OrderTeishoku;
   begin
   writeln('Choice For Teishoku:');
   writeln('1.Kara-Age Teishoku $45');
   writeln('2.Tonkatsu Teishoku $40');
   writeln('3.Sashimi Teishoku $35');
   writeln('4.Mix Fry Teishoku $39');
   writeln('Previous =0');
   writeln('Enter your choice: ');
   readln(tei);
   if tei=0
   then Menu
   else write('How many Teishoku do you want ? ');
   readln(ntei);
   case tei of
   1:TeiName:='Kara-Age Teishoku';
   2:TeiName:='Tonkatsu Teishoku';
   3:TeiName:='Sashimi Teishoku';
   4:TeiName:='Mix Fry Teishoku';
   end;
   if ntei>1 then
   case ntei of
      1:TeiMoney:=ntei*13;
      2:TeiMoney:=ntei*20;
      3:TeiMoney:=ntei*18;
      4:TeiMoney:=ntei*15;
      5:TeiMoney:=ntei*22;
      6:TeiMoney:=ntei*22;
   end;
   if ntei=1 then
   case tei of
      1:TeiMoney:=13;
      2:TeiMoney:=20;
      3:TeiMoney:=18;
      4:TeiMoney:=15;
      5:TeiMoney:=22;
      6:TeiMoney:=22;
   end;
 end;

procedure StoreMoney1;
begin
   Assign(Money,'C:\Users\jason\Desktop\Ho Chung Hin Sba\real 
pg\Money.txt');
  rewrite(Money);
   writeln(Money,RamenName,' ','*',nramen,' ',RamenMoney);
   close(Money);
end;

procedure StoreMoney2;
begin
   Assign(Money,'C:\Users\jason\Desktop\Ho Chung Hin Sba\real 
pg\Money.txt');
  rewrite(Money);
   writeln(Money,NigiName,' ','*',nnigi,' ',NigiMoney);
   close(Money);
end;

procedure StoreMoney3;
begin
   Assign(Money,'C:\Users\jason\Desktop\Ho Chung Hin Sba\real 
pg\Money.txt');
  rewrite(Money);
   writeln(Money,TeiName,' ','*',ntei,' ',TeiMoney);
   close(Money);
end;

procedure StoreMoney4;
begin
   Assign(Money,'C:\Users\jason\Desktop\Ho Chung Hin Sba\real 
pg\Money.txt');
  rewrite(Money);
   writeln(Money,SashimiName,' ','*',nsashimi,' ',SashimiMoney);
   close(Money);
end;

Procedure PrintOut;
begin
b:=1;
   reset(Money);
  while not EOF(Money) do
  begin
  readln(Money,i);
  a[b]:=i;
  writeln(a[b]);
  b:=b+1;
  end;
  close(Money);
  end;

begin
   repeat
      begin
        Menu
   end;
   if choice=1 then
   begin
   OrderRamen;
   StoreMoney1;
   end
   else if choice=2 then
   begin
   OrderNigirizushi;
   StoreMoney2;
   end
   else if choice=3 then
   begin
   OrderTeishoku;
   StoreMoney3;
   end
   else if choice=4 then
   begin
   OrderSashimi;
   StoreMoney4;
   end;
  until choice=5;
  if choice=5 then
  begin
     PrintOut
  end;
  if choice=9 then
   exit;


end.
```

Result and input:
input 1 1 1 , 2 1 1
result : Detail of 2 but no 1
please help!

Comment: It would help if you specified *which* Pascal you are using. There are a number of different Pascals with varying syntactic differences. Seeing you are using `Assign`, it is probably Turbo Pascal/Borland Pascal or FreePascal, but I could be wrong. Which is it?

Comment: it is Free Turbo Pascal

Comment: Are you kidding me? FreePascal or Turbo Pascal?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - I believe that the Borland Computer Museum has actually made some legacy versions of TP available as freebies; the querent may be referring to one of those... but, yes, he should clarify.

Comment: No connection to your question, but your code is bloated. In all the Order procedures, you check whether the variable is greater than one, then multiply the quantity by the prices. If the variable is equal to one, you return the price. This second part is unnecessary: multiplying the price by the quantity - even if it is 1 - will give you the correct result.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: Yes, i guess you are right. But if people want something cheap, then TP is nice for old, nostalgic people like me (I started with TP3 and did a lot with BP7 as well), but otherwise, if you want "free as in beer", I think FreePascal/Lazarus is a much better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `StoreMoney` procedures all open the text file for writing, discarding the content previously written. You need to find the compiler's procedure/function that will open the text file for writing-with-append. I have seen several ways of doing this, such as `Append(f)` and `Open(f,'a')`, as well as object-oriented (or pseudo-object-oriented) styles such as `F.Open('a')` or `F.Append()`.

Comment: If this has solved your problem, please "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark below the upvote/downvote arrows next to the answer. It indicates that the problem has been satisfactorily addressed (and gives me a few more points of 'rep').